# Using variables in an expression

Tags: 8, theming

I am checking for a specific block in a specific theme region.

```
{% if page.header_first.blockmachinename %}
   // Show stuff
{% endif %}
```

This works when I have the right machine name. But I want to be able to use a variable in place of `blockmachinename`.

Something like this, which of course doesn't work.

```
{% if page.header_first.{{ the_variable }} %}
```

This also didn't work, as expected

```
{% set block_name = 'page.header_first.' ~ the_variable %}
{% if block_name %}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Use Twig's [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the dot syntax can mean a lot of different things, try to make it more clear by using the array syntax:

```
{% set the_variable = 'mytheme_myblock' %}

{% if page.header_first[the_variable] %}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

you were very close !  try twigs "in" . for explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319011/if-a-true-or-b-true-statement

```
// remove the first line obviously. 
{% set  blockmachinename  = 'hello' %}
{{ blockmachinename }}

{% set full_block_name = 'page.header_first.' ~ blockmachinename %}

{{ full_block_name }}

{% if full_block_name in ['page.header_first.hello'] %}

    <h1>Cool things go here.</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I realize my question was ambiguous which is my bad! This isn't quite what I need, but it is _very_ useful and I'm sure I'll need it later. Thank you!